# Pegar um arquivo em uma pasta

Tags: c

Eu preciso pegar um arquivo com certa extenção para abrir no fopen, mas não sei o nome do arquivo, só sei que ele está na mesma pasta da main, teria alguma forma dentro da main de saber quais os arquivos da mesma pasta da main que contém a extenção que preciso?
Ex: na pasta tem a main.c e um teste.txt (no caso eu não sei o nome do arquivo, somente que ele é .txt), e gostaria de abrir o teste.txt na main pelo fopen (ou se tiver outro comando).
Espero que tenha ficado claro, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste exemplo tenho o codigo na pasta:
"/home/ricardo/Desktop/teste/"

Pretendo ler os ficheiros .txt na pasta:
"/home/ricardo/Desktop/teste/txtfolder"

Nesta pasta tenho ainda outros ficheiros que não são '.txt'

[image: Diretorio que pretendo inspecionar]

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <errno.h>
//#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    
    //Diretoria onde estao os ficheiros .txt
    char path[1000]="/home/ricardo/Desktop/teste/txtfolder";
    
    d = opendir(path);
    char full_path[1000];
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            //Verifica se é um ficheiro regular.
            if(dir->d_type==DT_REG)
            {
                full_path[0]='\0';
                strcat(full_path,path);
                strcat(full_path,"/");
                strcat(full_path,dir->d_name);
                printf("\n\n%s\n",full_path);
        
                //Verifica se o ficheiro é '.txt'
                if(strstr(dir->d_name, ".txt") != NULL) 
                {
                      printf("%s\n",dir->d_name);
                }
        
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: acho que entendi, obrigado

Comment: Valida se responde à tua duvida, aceita a resposta como válida e dá up vote. Thanks!